# Are there any platforms for which the file separator isn't "/"?

Tags: r, cross-platform

To create a path to a file in a platform independent way, you are *supposed to* use `file.path`.  It bugs me a little that, e.g.,

```
file.path("some dir", "some other dir", "my file")
```

is more characters and less readable than

```
"some dir/some other dir/my file"
```

I want to know if there are any platforms for which the second version will fail.  Certainly the path separator (`.Platform$file.sep`) is `/` for Linux, Mac and Windows.

Are there any platforms (that R runs on) which have a different value of `.Platform$file.sep`?

EDIT:
The the only current platforms from the [Wikipedia list](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Representations_of_paths_by_operating_system_and_shell) (thanks darioo) that don't use `/` are OpenVMS, Stratus VOS and Symbian.  The [FAQ on R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-machines-does-R-run-on_003f) states that R is developed for

> the Unix-like, Windows and Mac
>   families of operating systems

So there is no official support for any of these platforms.  I don't have a good feel for whether or not there's an army of hackers running R on their Nokia phones.  Can you guesstimate a probability that anyone uses R on these systems?

Comment: It's possible to run R on OpenVMS (where separator is '.'), but I suspect you could easily discard this platform.

Comment: `file.path` is more readable when you use parametrized paths. Compare `file.path(main_path, subfolder, "Analysis 001")` vs `paste(main_path, subfolder, "Analysis 001", sep="/")`.

Comment: file.path() was probably introduced back when Mac classic OS (: separator) was still supported ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a [list of operating systems with their file separators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Representations_of_paths_by_operating_system_and_shell).

Compare it with the list of OS's on which R runs and you'll have a reference list.

Although, you'll probably stumble upon `/` in 99% of situations.

Comment: awesome reference @darioo!

Answer (score 5):

\ is the traditional pathseperator in Windows. Some modern Windows Apps, API's handle both versions. But the old style is still the primary.

Comment: R handles happily / on Windows as well. Thank God it does. Or thank the R-core team actually...

Comment: In R, you need to use / for paths in Windows - conversion to \ is done underneath the bonnet.

Comment: Windows cmd line commands typically use / to mean a switch or flag and \ to be a path separator so there is potential for problems.  e.g. shell("copy /a/b c") will be interpreted as copy c to the current directory using switches a and b (as opposed to copying \a\b to c).