# How to make compatible directory paths in R

Tags: r, directory, operating-system, compatibility

In R, the `file.path()` function allows me to define the name of the directories and the name of the file in a way that the path created is compatible between Unix-based and Windows OS. However, I cannot use it for directories, since they need a trailing slash, and this one is OS dependent.

example:
for a file located in /home/dir1/dir2/file.txt (Unix-based system) with `file.path()` will be transformed in windows (I think, I do not have a windows to compare) to \home\dir1\dir2\file.txt when using `file.path("home", "dir1", "dir2", "file.txt")`.

Is there a function in R that allows me to create paths for directories compatible with all OS systems?
I want to be able to store in a vector the path to the directory correctly in each system when someone uses my code:

- Unix-based : "/home/dir1/dir2/"
- Windows: "\home\dir1\dir2\ "

Any idea will be welcomed! Thanks in advance for your time.

Update:
I decided to extract the dir after creating a dummy file path using `dirname(file.path("home", "dir1", "dir2", "*.*")` and when creating the full path with each of the files I need to access, I just created each with `paste0()` and `sep=.Platform$file.sep` as argument for `paste0()`

Comment: Read about here package - https://cran.r-project.org/package=here

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say directories need a trailing slash? On both my Windows and Ubuntu systems if I run `dir("./dir1")` with no trailing slash, R lists the files in that directory. Which operating systems require the trailing slash and for what purpose? Also it's worth checking out [Are there any platforms for which the file separator isn't "/"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459969/are-there-any-platforms-for-which-the-file-separator-isnt).

Comment: I was trying to change from hardcoded paths for my files to a more general, and I noticed that by just putting together the name of the file and the dir, the / was not added and my address did not work. That is why I thought that if file.path()  existed, same for a dir was possible. In the "update" I have place my solution. I suppose it will work across all platforms now.

Comment: @Luisa OK if you're happy with your solution then do you still have a question or should this be closed?

Comment: @SamR: I am happy ;-) Thanks. Yes, you can close it. I hope it helps somebody in the future. Thanks for all your comments and help.